# Cracks appearing on window and door frames (not the wall) all over a newly purchased home

Tags: doors, cracks, window-frame

I've noticed thin cracks becoming visible on multiple door and window frames where the horizontal and vertical wood of the frames join (*on the corners*.)

It appears they were just painted over and they are all reappearing. I also noticed 2 of the doors have become harder to open/close in the last few weeks. Moved into the house in the summer and this began in the winter.

Could it be weather related?

We've discovered other evidence of shoddy work by the developers so I'm concerned this may be a sign of something much more serious.

[image]

Comment: Is that a single-pane window that the frame is completely made out of wood?  It kind of looks smooth enough to be a vinyl window frame.  If it's single pane then are you in a cold climate?

Comment: It's a double pane window. The frame is wooden, I believe. Winter temps tend to be between 25-40 degrees in the region.

Comment: If it is a double paned window in a wood frame then I do not believe you have a seal with the airspace in between the glass.  (maybe you might, if the glass is seated in a rubber gasket and all of that)  If that is the case and it's just an old-school unsealed double paned window then it is just cheap construction, and I would have the windows replaced with modern vinyl ones using sealed glass (maybe even go triple pane) since your energy savings would pay for the cost of the window.  Start with the biggest one first.  At some point you have to write off what you have instead of repairing it.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. The same thing is happening with all the doorframes, too. That is why I thought it might be foundation related. Any idea what might be causing the issue with the doors?

Comment: Trim wood had high moisture content when installed itis shrinking as it dries

Comment: What @kris said, above. Plus, summer is generally more humid; winter is generally less humid, so wood will move as it changes moisture content. Doors that need to be tuned up after a seasonal change are not uncommon -- I wouldn't use that as evidence that the house has more serious problems.

Comment: I hate to berate this but are you absolutely sure the part of the window the glass goes into is indeed wood?  it really looks like vinyl.  The frame around the outside of the windows and doors is usually wood (or mdf) trim and not part of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much just normal shrinkage in winter as things dry out, possibly aggravated by using damp wood or not running A/C in the hot/wet summertime - so if replaced/installed/painted before you moved in in the summer, it would be swelled up, and as you run heat and indoor humidity falls in the winter, the wood shrinks.

Personally I'd suggest waiting through a year or two before fixing it unless it's the top of your spousal unit's issues with life in general or the house in specific - once it's "cycled" a few times it will move less (not none) in the future so a fix will be more likely to stay fixed. But's basically paintable caulk and paint to fix it, nothing major to get excited about.